# React Owl Carousal responsive not working

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

*I have few owl carousals on my website. but anything isn't working in responsive screens. following is my code for one of the carousels.*

```
export default function HomeMovieSlider() {
  
    return (
  <div>
    <OwlCarousel className='owl-theme'
    loop center margin={1} autoplay ={true} dots={false} items={3} touchDrag={true} lazyLoad={true} 
    
    // responsive={"0:{items:1,},600:{items:3,},1000:{items:5,}"}
    animateOut={'fadeOut'} animateIn={'flipInX'}>
    {MOVIEBANNER.map((movieBannertop) => {
        return (
            <div  >
                {/* <h4>{movieBannerp.movieTitle}</h4> */}
                {/* <img src={movieBannertop.bannerImage}/> */}
                <Card style={{width: "250px"}}> 
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={movieBannertop.bannerImage} height="380" max-width= "100% !important"/>
                    <Card.Body> 
                      <Card.Title as="h6" ><b>{movieBannertop.movieTitle}</b></Card.Title>
                      <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{movieBannertop.genres}</Card.Subtitle>
                      <Link to="/MovieDetail"><small className="text-muted">More Details</small></Link>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer className="text-center">
                      
                      <Button variant="danger" style={{backgroundColor: "#ff4444"}}><Link to="/movieBooking" style={{color: "#fff"}}>Book Now</Link></Button>
                    </Card.Footer> 
                  </Card> 
            </div>  
        );
      })}
    </OwlCarousel>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

> [mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKpth.png) [medium screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In8Mb.png) [full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY8cy.png)

Comment: It "isn't working" is not enough detail to debug a problem. Please explain the problem in as much detail as you can, bare in mind we don't know what you are seeing or what you are trying to achieve unless you tell us.

Comment: @DBS updated please check